# Hide context menu on task pane Excel office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I developed an Excel Add-in (Task pane) with office.js. I would like to hide the default context menu which appear in top right corner:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported. Please add a suggestion on user voice for consideration. Thank you. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16512777)

Comment: @DonaldDuck He works in Microsoft (i.e. the developer of the program in question). Humberto - next time, please state clearly that you are one of the developers of the software in question (if this is indeed the case).

Comment: This post should be made as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @PeterHall No, it *provides an answer*: "You can't do that right now".